# AngularJS $index always 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, indexing

i am having a problem with angularjs and  $index

i give it at a parameter to a function. It works at HTML in {{}} ({{$index}} works).   But it doesnt work in the function. I alert the index and its always 0...

I used it at another position in my project and it works fine..

Here is the code.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="rounded1" ng-click="setClickEvent($index)" ng-model="clickStatus"/>
```

JS File with the function:

```
$scope.setClickEvent = function(index) {
  alert(index);
```

};

the alert is always 0....

i hope someone could help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Also share the markup associated with ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using this `<input>` tag in an `ng-repeat` directive.  `$index` will show 0 unless it's used in an `ng-repeat` where it will count from 0 to n.

Perhaps you meant to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="setClickEvent($index)" ng-model="clickStatus"/>
</div>
```

I removed the ID because each of the 5 checkboxes would have the same ID which isn't valid.

Comment: OP said using {{$index}} in html works just fine. I *think* it **is** inside of an ng-repeat, the code is just not included, which is why Rayon asked for the associated ng-repeat code.

Comment: I suspect that he's not using an ng-repeat which is why $index is always 0.  I guess we need more info from the OP to really figure this out.

Comment: Yes, that was my original thought as well.. it seems to make the most sense. However, since the OP said {{$index}} works just fine, it seems to me that it is a different issue, we'll need more context to confirm

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, here is the whole html code with the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="frage in frageListe">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="container-fluid list-group-item ">
                <div class="rounded">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="rounded1" ng-click="setClickEvent(frage.id)" ng-model="clickStatus"/>
                    <label for="rounded1"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="list-text">
                    <h3 class="list-group-item-heading quest-list-text serif">{{frage.titel}} {{$index}}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="divider-line-questlist">            

        </div>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution on this? I have the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant, but I had the same problem. For me the issue was that I was nesting multiple ng-repeats. To solve this I set aliases for the indexes with ng-init.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

```
<script>
  angular.module('initExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']];
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div ng-repeat="innerList in list" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
    <div ng-repeat="value in innerList" ng-init="innerIndex = $index">
       <span class="example-init">list[ {{outerIndex}} ][ {{innerIndex}} ] = {{value}};</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```